# org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn valve portability

Tags: tomcat, tomcat-valve

I am thinking of using the tomcat `org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn` valve for my single sign on, as documented [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Single_Sign_On)

If I go with this approach, what would I need to do to my applications if I decide to move my application from tomcat to another web container such as jboss, glassfish, weblogic, or websphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that Tomcat's SSO shouldn't require you to change anything about your webapp. That means that your webapps are still fully-portable -- at least individually.

If you want to move to, say Websphere, you'll have to figure out how to use that container's SSO mechanism.